# EditText Binding from View in Kotlin not working

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

I am trying to update an EditText from View page in Kotlin using mvvm. But when ViewModel is initialised the default value is binding but when i change the value from EditText onClick listener its not updating the UI.

xml

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/itemsDatePicker"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:text="@={itemviewmodel.selectedDateText}"
                android:onClick="@{itemviewmodel.datePickerOnClick}"
                android:hint="Select Date"

                tools:ignore="AutoFill,TextFields" />
```

View Model

```
fun datePickerOnClick(view: View) {
    showDatePicker.value=true
}
```

View

```
vm.showDatePicker.observe(this,androidx.lifecycle.Observer{ s->
        val myCalendar: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()

        val date =
            DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { view, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth -> // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year)
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear)
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth)

                //This place should update the ui with selected date but not working as expected
                vm.selectedDateText.value =DateHelper.getTodayDate(myCalendar.getTime())
            }

        DatePickerDialog(
            this, date, myCalendar
                .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        ).show()
    })
```

Any help to overcome this problem is much appreciated.
Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Is this onClick method executed? And can You add the whole VM code?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about dataBinding, and i assume that you already have it in your dependencies.

Then...

1. Check if you contained you xml mainLayout with `<layout></layout>`
2. Check if you you have made an instance of that layout on top of onCreate in your mainActivity. For ex: `private lateinit var mainBinding: ActivityMainBinding`
3. Use that instance/variable to also get the editText for ex: `mainBinding.itemsDatePicker`